# Symfony sql get sub sum of query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query that returns the sum of the 'minutes worked' column in the database, which is grouped by users. Is there a way to break the sum down further in the same query. for example the sum of minutes worked where the charge is zero, charge is 1 etc.

Does this require a subquery? is it possible to just write multiple select statements? here is my current query.

```
$repository->createQueryBuilder('w')
->select('sum(w.minutesWorked) as Total_Worked,w, u') 
->join('w.user','u') 
->groupBy('w.user')
```

Any help in the correct way to approach this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just group by charge too, and the sum must work as you need.

```
select sum(w.minutesWorked), w.charge,u.id from table1 w
INNER JOIN user u on u.id = w.idUser
GROUP BY u.id, w.charge ;
```

If you need an specific charge value just use a where

```
WHERE w.charge in (0,1,2,3)
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks, it's not the solution i'm after as i need the total sum and a few variations on that total. It still helps though.